Computer Modern font looks thinner on Beamer
I'm using the following package to make a poster using beamer:
https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini
I edited the .sty file and removed all of the font settings and just replaced it with \usefonttheme{serif}.
However, the font looks a lot thinner and less wide than the way it normally looks on a regular latex pdf.
Is this some quirk of beamer? Is there any method of simply changing the font weight or thickness so that it matches what it would look like on a normal latex document?
(Font on beamer poster)

(Font on a regular latex document)

I apologise for not being able to provide a MWE, I really don't know enough about beamer to do this.
This is the edited .sty file:
% Gemini theme
% https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini

% ====================
% Dependencies
% ====================

\RequirePackage{exscale}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{calc}

% ====================
% Fonts
% ====================

%\newfontfamily\Helvetica[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica}
%\newfontfamily\TimesNowLight[Ligatures=TeX]{Times Now Light}
%\newfontfamily\Lato[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}

\usefonttheme{serif}

%\setsansfont{Lato}[
%  UprightFont=*-Light,
%  ItalicFont=*-LightItalic,
%  BoldFont=*-Regular,
%  BoldItalicFont=*-Italic
%]
%

\setbeamerfont{headline}{}
\setbeamerfont{headline title}{size=\Huge,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{headline author}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{headline institute}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{heading}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}

% ====================
% Macros
% ====================

\newcommand{\samelineand}{\qquad}

% ====================
% Elements
% ====================

% List
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
\topsep 1ex % spacing before
\parsep 0\p@ \@plus\p@
\itemsep 0.5ex} % spacing between

% Itemize

\setbeamerte{itemize item}{\raise0.5ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.3ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\raise0.2ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}

% Enumerate

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertsubenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\insertsubsubenumlabel.}

% Equation
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex}

% Caption
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}

% Bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

% Navigation
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

% ====================
% Components
% ====================

% Heading
\newcommand\heading[1]
{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\usebeamerfont{heading}\usebeamercolor[fg]{heading}#1}\par\smallskip
}

% logo
\newlength{\logoleftwidth}
\setlength{\logoleftwidth}{0cm}
\newlength{\logorightwidth}
\setlength{\logorightwidth}{0cm}
\newlength{\maxlogowidth}  % space on both sides set to maxlogowidth to keep title centered
\setlength{\maxlogowidth}{0cm}

\newcommand{\logoright}[1]{
  \newcommand{\insertlogoright}{#1}
  \settowidth{\logorightwidth}{\insertlogoright}
  \addtolength{\logorightwidth}{10ex}
  \setlength{\maxlogowidth}{\maxof{\logoleftwidth}{\logorightwidth}}
}
\newcommand{\logoleft}[1]{
  \newcommand{\insertlogoleft}{#1}
  \settowidth{\logoleftwidth}{\insertlogoleft}
  \addtolength{\logoleftwidth}{10ex}
  \setlength{\maxlogowidth}{\maxof{\logoleftwidth}{\logorightwidth}}
}

% Headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{headline}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{\maxlogowidth}
        \vskip5ex
        \ifdefined\insertlogoleft
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \hspace{10ex}
        \raggedright
        \insertlogoleft
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \else\fi
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\maxlogowidth-\maxlogowidth}
        \usebeamerfont{headline}
        \vskip3ex
        \centering
        \ifx \inserttitle \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline title}\inserttitle\\[0.5ex]}
        \fi
        \ifx \beamer@shortauthor \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline author}\insertauthor\\[1ex]}
        \fi
        \ifx \insertinstitute \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline institute}\insertinstitute\\[1ex]}
        \fi
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{\maxlogowidth}
        \vskip5ex
        \ifdefined\insertlogoright
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \raggedleft
        \insertlogoright
        \hspace{10ex}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \else\fi
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vspace{5ex}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{headline rule}{}{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=0.5ex]{headline rule}\end{beamercolorbox}
    }
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Block
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block body}
  \justifying
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}
{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Alert Block
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block alerted title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block alerted separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block alerted body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Example Block
\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block example title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block example separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block example body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Footer
\newcommand{\footercontent}[1]{\newcommand{\insertfootercontent}{#1}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \ifdefined\insertfootercontent
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[vmode]{headline}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{headline rule}{}{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=0.25ex]{headline rule}\end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    \vspace{1.5ex}
    \hspace{\sepwidth}
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \centering
    \insertfootercontent
    \hspace{\sepwidth}
    \vspace{1.5ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \else\fi
}


This is the poster.tex file, which is the same as from the github repo.
% Gemini theme
% https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

% ====================
% Packages
% ====================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=72,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{gemini}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

% ====================
% Lengths
% ====================

% If you have N columns, choose \sepwidth and \colwidth such that
% (N+1)*\sepwidth + N*\colwidth = \paperwidth
\newlength{\sepwidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\sepwidth}{0.025\paperwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{0.3\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}

% ====================
% Title
% ====================

\title{Some fancy title: followed by some more text}

\author{Alyssa P. Hacker \inst{1} \and Ben Bitdiddle \inst{2} \and Lem E. Tweakit \inst{2}}

\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Some Institute \samelineand \inst{2} Another Institute}

% ====================
% Footer (optional)
% ====================

\footercontent{
  \href{https://www.example.com}{https://www.example.com} \hfill
  ABC Conference 2025, New York --- XYZ-1234 \hfill
  \href{mailto:alyssa.p.hacker@example.com}{alyssa.p.hacker@example.com}}
% (can be left out to remove footer)

% ====================
% Logo (optional)
% ====================

% use this to include logos on the left and/or right side of the header:
% \logoright{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{logo1.pdf}}
% \logoleft{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{logo2.pdf}}

% ====================
% Body
% ====================

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

  \begin{block}{A block title}

    Some block contents, followed by a diagram, followed by a dummy paragraph.

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
        \draw[step=0.25cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
        \draw (1,0) -- (0.2,0.2) -- (0,1) -- (-0.2,0.2) -- (-1,0)
          -- (-0.2,-0.2) -- (0,-1) -- (0.2,-0.2) -- cycle;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{A figure caption.}
    \end{figure}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultricies
    eget libero ac ullamcorper. Integer et euismod ante. Aenean vestibulum
    lobortis augue, ut lobortis turpis rhoncus sed. Proin feugiat nibh a
    lacinia dignissim. Proin scelerisque, risus eget tempor fermentum, ex
    turpis condimentum urna, quis malesuada sapien arcu eu purus.

  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{A block containing a list}

    Nam vulputate nunc felis, non condimentum lacus porta ultrices. Nullam sed
    sagittis metus. Etiam consectetur gravida urna quis suscipit.

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textbf{Mauris tempor} risus nulla, sed ornare
      \item \textbf{Libero tincidunt} a duis congue vitae
      \item \textbf{Dui ac pretium} morbi justo neque, ullamcorper
    \end{itemize}

    Eget augue porta, bibendum venenatis tortor.

  \end{block}

  \begin{alertblock}{A highlighted block}

    This block catches your eye, so \textbf{important stuff} should probably go
    here.

    Curabitur eu libero vehicula, cursus est fringilla, luctus est. Morbi
    consectetur mauris quam, at finibus elit auctor ac. Aliquam erat volutpat.
    Aenean at nisl ut ex ullamcorper eleifend et eu augue. Aenean quis velit
    tristique odio convallis ultrices a ac odio.

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textbf{Fusce dapibus tellus} vel tellus semper finibus. In
        consequat, nibh sed mattis luctus, augue diam fermentum lectus.
      \item \textbf{In euismod erat metus} non ex. Vestibulum luctus augue in
        mi condimentum, at sollicitudin lorem viverra.
      \item \textbf{Suspendisse vulputate} mauris vel placerat consectetur.
        Mauris semper, purus ac hendrerit molestie, elit mi dignissim odio, in
        suscipit felis sapien vel ex.
    \end{itemize}

    Aenean tincidunt risus eros, at gravida lorem sagittis vel. Vestibulum ante
    ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.

  \end{alertblock}

\end{column}

\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

  \begin{block}{A block containing an enumerated list}

    Vivamus congue volutpat elit non semper. Praesent molestie nec erat ac
    interdum. In quis suscipit erat. \textbf{Phasellus mauris felis, molestie
    ac pharetra quis}, tempus nec ante. Donec finibus ante vel purus mollis
    fermentum. Sed felis mi, pharetra eget nibh a, feugiat eleifend dolor. Nam
    mollis condimentum purus quis sodales. Nullam eu felis eu nulla eleifend
    bibendum nec eu lorem. Vivamus felis velit, volutpat ut facilisis ac,
    commodo in metus.

    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \textbf{Morbi mauris purus}, egestas at vehicula et, convallis
        accumsan orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      \item \textbf{Cras vehicula blandit urna ut maximus}. Aliquam blandit nec
        massa ac sollicitudin. Curabitur cursus, metus nec imperdiet bibendum,
        velit lectus faucibus dolor, quis gravida metus mauris gravida turpis.
      \item \textbf{Vestibulum et massa diam}. Phasellus fermentum augue non
        nulla accumsan, non rhoncus lectus condimentum.
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Fusce aliquam magna velit}

    Et rutrum ex euismod vel. Pellentesque ultricies, velit in fermentum
    vestibulum, lectus nisi pretium nibh, sit amet aliquam lectus augue vel
    velit. Suspendisse rhoncus massa porttitor augue feugiat molestie. Sed
    molestie ut orci nec malesuada. Sed ultricies feugiat est fringilla
    posuere.

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            no markers,
            domain=0:2*pi,
            samples=100,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={-},
            ticks=none]
          \addplot[red] {sin(deg(x))};
          \addplot[blue] {cos(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Another figure caption.}
    \end{figure}

  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Nam cursus consequat egestas}

    Nulla eget sem quam. Ut aliquam volutpat nisi vestibulum convallis. Nunc a
    lectus et eros facilisis hendrerit eu non urna. Interdum et malesuada fames
    ac ante \textit{ipsum primis} in faucibus. Etiam sit amet velit eget sem
    euismod tristique. Praesent enim erat, porta vel mattis sed, pharetra sed
    ipsum. Morbi commodo condimentum massa, \textit{tempus venenatis} massa
    hendrerit quis. Maecenas sed porta est. Praesent mollis interdum lectus,
    sit amet sollicitudin risus tincidunt non.

    Etiam sit amet tempus lorem, aliquet condimentum velit. Donec et nibh
    consequat, sagittis ex eget, dictum orci. Etiam quis semper ante. Ut eu
    mauris purus. Proin nec consectetur ligula. Mauris pretium molestie
    ullamcorper. Integer nisi neque, aliquet et odio non, sagittis porta justo.

    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textbf{Sed consequat} id ante vel efficitur. Praesent congue massa
        sed est scelerisque, elementum mollis augue iaculis.
        \begin{itemize}
          \item In sed est finibus, vulputate
            nunc gravida, pulvinar lorem. In maximus nunc dolor, sed auctor eros
            porttitor quis.
          \item Fusce ornare dignissim nisi. Nam sit amet risus vel lacus
            tempor tincidunt eu a arcu.
          \item Donec rhoncus vestibulum erat, quis aliquam leo
            gravida egestas.
        \end{itemize}
      \item \textbf{Sed luctus, elit sit amet} dictum maximus, diam dolor
        faucibus purus, sed lobortis justo erat id turpis.
      \item \textbf{Pellentesque facilisis dolor in leo} bibendum congue.
        Maecenas congue finibus justo, vitae eleifend urna facilisis at.
    \end{itemize}

  \end{block}

\end{column}

\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

  \begin{exampleblock}{A highlighted block containing some math}

    A different kind of highlighted block.

    $$
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}
    $$

    Interdum et malesuada fames $\{1, 4, 9, \ldots\}$ ac ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus. Cras eleifend dolor eu nulla suscipit suscipit. Sed lobortis non
    felis id vulputate.

    \heading{A heading inside a block}

    Praesent consectetur mi $x^2 + y^2$ metus, nec vestibulum justo viverra
    nec. Proin eget nulla pretium, egestas magna aliquam, mollis neque. Vivamus
    dictum $\mathbf{u}^\intercal\mathbf{v}$ sagittis odio, vel porta erat
    congue sed. Maecenas ut dolor quis arcu auctor porttitor.

    \heading{Another heading inside a block}

    Sed augue erat, scelerisque a purus ultricies, placerat porttitor neque.
    Donec $P(y \mid x)$ fermentum consectetur $\nabla_x P(y \mid x)$ sapien
    sagittis egestas. Duis eget leo euismod nunc viverra imperdiet nec id
    justo.

  \end{exampleblock}

  \begin{block}{Nullam vel erat at velit convallis laoreet}

    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus libero enim, gravida sed erat sit amet,
    scelerisque congue diam. Fusce dapibus dui ut augue pulvinar iaculis.

    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{l r r c}
        \toprule
        \textbf{First column} & \textbf{Second column} & \textbf{Third column} & \textbf{Fourth} \\
        \midrule
        Foo & 13.37 & 384,394 & $\alpha$ \\
        Bar & 2.17 & 1,392 & $\beta$ \\
        Baz & 3.14 & 83,742 & $\delta$ \\
        Qux & 7.59 & 974 & $\gamma$ \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{A table caption.}
    \end{table}

    Donec quis posuere ligula. Nunc feugiat elit a mi malesuada consequat. Sed
    imperdiet augue ac nibh aliquet tristique. Aenean eu tortor vulputate,
    eleifend lorem in, dictum urna. Proin auctor ante in augue tincidunt
    tempor. Proin pellentesque vulputate odio, ac gravida nulla posuere
    efficitur. Aenean at velit vel dolor blandit molestie. Mauris laoreet
    commodo quam, non luctus nibh ullamcorper in. Class aptent taciti sociosqu
    ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

    Nulla varius finibus volutpat. Mauris molestie lorem tincidunt, iaculis
    libero at, gravida ante. Phasellus at felis eu neque suscipit suscipit.
    Integer ullamcorper, dui nec pretium ornare, urna dolor consequat libero,
    in feugiat elit lorem euismod lacus. Pellentesque sit amet dolor mollis,
    auctor urna non, tempus sem.

  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{References}

    \nocite{*}
    \footnotesize{\bibliographystyle{plain}\bibliography{poster}}

  \end{block}

\end{column}

\separatorcolumn
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Please always include a compilable test document in your questions! We need to see which packages you use, which poster and font size you have etc.

The example you linked to does not use computer modern.

If I use \usefonttheme{serif} and remove the fontspec package does it not just default to the regular latex font?

The example you linked to loads other fonts, e.g. latin modern. If you don't show us a reproducible example, how shall we know if your code also loads other fonts?

I added my .sty file

Please add a compilable test document. The linked example changes the font in the document itself. We need to know if you do this as well.

\usepackage{lmodern}: you are not using computer modern fonts. Do you use the same fonts in your non-beamer document?

You shouldn't combine \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with \RequirePackage{fontspec}

I removed both but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Again: do you use the same fonts in your non-beamer document, which you still haven't shown us? And do you compile them in the same way?

My non beamer document is literally just \documentclass{article} \begin{document} text \end{document}

Please run pdffonts (or use something similar) on both pdf files, and update your question with information on what fonts it reports.

@Apollonius Then your poster uses the latin modern font and your non-beamer document does not use it. Different fonts will look differently.

Will it use latin modern even though I have removed the \usepacakage{lmodern} line?

@Apollonius You can find out using pdffonts or many PDF viewers will tell you this in the properties of the document. Without being sure what you have an haven't removed, it is impossible to say. gemini loads fontspec. If that works, you're using a Unicode engine and probably using Latin Modern. LuaTeX defaults to Latin Modern, for example, whereas pdfTeX defaults to Computer Modern.

Btw, just in case you want slightly thicker CM fonts, you can take a look at the newcomputermodern or mlmodern fonts. I believe a newcm sans math font is in development as well.
